# get first occurrence of pattern

Tags: r, regex

I'm pretty new to regex so I might look silly but I've done a lot of searching and I'm not able to get it by myself.

Original string :

```
blabla\ni want that\nblabla\nblabalbla\nblabla
```

What I want to get :

```
[1] i want that
```

i.e. first occurrence of a string between two \n

I tried to do it with gsub. It seems easy as hell but I'm stucked.

I'm using R with PCRE synthax

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please, show yours attempts and their results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use basic regex with `sub` to match zero or more characters that are not a `\n` (`[^\n]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `\n`, then one or more characters that are not a `\n`, capture as a group (`([^\n]+)`) followed by characters to the end of the string and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of that captured group

```
sub("^[^\n]*\n([^\n]+).*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "i want that"
```